# Open a page after cliking on a push notification Ionic 2 iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugin-fcm

Lately, I have been adding push notifications capability on my app. I am using FCN plugin found on this [link](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm) and I developing using Ionic 2 framework. The notifications get delivered but when I tap on it it just opens the homepage of the app, and not the inner page that I need.

I have used this code

```
declare var FCMPlugin;
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = HomePage;
  horoscopePage:any = HoroscopeHomePage;
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

   **********************

    FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(data){
      if(data.wasTapped){
        //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
        if(data.topic =="horoskopi" && data.type=="list"){

        console.log( JSON.stringify(data) );

        this.nav.push(this.horoscopePage);

        }

      }else{

        if(data.topic =="horoskopi" && data.type=="list"){

        console.log( JSON.stringify(data) );

        this.nav.push(this.horoscopePage);
        }
      }
  });
  });
```

Somehow this line of code `this.nav.push(this.horoscopePage);` doesn't do anything

When I use NavController instead it gives me this error:

```
MyApp_Host.html:1 ERROR Error: No provider for NavController!
    at injectionError (core.es5.js:1231)
    at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1269)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2770)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2809)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (core.es5.js:2741)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.es5.js:2610)
    at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (core.es5.js:3578)
    at resolveDep (core.es5.js:11039)
    at createClass (core.es5.js:10903)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10723)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `public navCtrl: NavController` into `constructor` then change code as

```
this.navCtrl.push(this.horoscopePage);
```

Comment: Dr. Geek I have tried that but when I install the app on the device it gives me a blank screen after the splash screen has finished loading.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46139512/how-can-i-decrease-the-ionic-cordova-project-start-duration

Comment: I don't know if I was correct in explaining the problem. The app gives me a blank screen only when I add NavController in app.component.ts class. If I remove it the app opens as usual.

Comment: Dr. Geek I have updated the question with the error that the app gives me when using NavController

Comment: Could u share the project files to check the problem because normally it has to be worked...

Answer (score 0):

Well after I took a look at the official documentation of Ionic, I found out that we can't use `NavController` in `app.component.ts`  because you can't inject `NavController` because any components that are navigation controllers are children of the `root component` so they aren't available to be injected. For more click [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/).

The reason that I was unable to push a new `Page` inside `FCM.onNotifications()` functions was that it changed the `scope` of application. The solutions was simple: just use the arrow function:

```
FCMPlugin.onNotification(
        (data)=>{
            if(data.wasTapped){ 
             //do something
            } 
            else {     
              //do something
           }
      });
```

Comment: I'm using the arrow function too but still getting the same error.